# Does Cronet support requests queueing?What is the limit?

Tags: chromium, cronet

Does Cronet support queueing outgoing requests when using HTTP/2 or QUIC? and if so, is it unbounded/has large limit? Is an error returned if the application exceeds the max allowed in-flight requests?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the same Cronet engine, it uses Chrome's connection limit and request queuing behavior. The allowed limit of simultaneous in-flight requests/streams is 256 for Http2 and 100 for Quic. No, there is no error when exceeding the max, we just delay creating the streams until there are free slots on the session.